# web2py: how to update multiple fields in table

Tags: python, web2py

I try to update multiple fields in a table by passing a dict
is there any way to do this in web2py like `bulk_insert` without using `SQLFORM`

```
def myupdate(self):
    return db(db.table.id == id).update({'field1': self.field1, 'field2': self.filed2})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass them in as parameters:

```
def myupdate( self ):
    return db( db.table.id == id ).update( field1 = self.field1,
                                           field2 = self.field2
                                           )
```

Or if you already have the dict in a variable:

```
def myupdate( self ):
    return db( **dictvar )
```